# How much precise are the Google maps coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cartography

First of all... I do not know if this is a valid question here. If not please tell me a site to ask for help in this.

My question is about the coordinates of google maps... how accurate they are? I mean what exactly they mark... it is a region? for example a circle of 1 km of diameter... or really is is the exactly point where you are stand?

If it is a big region the next question does not have sense I think...

If it is exactly a point, it is possible to ubicate that point in google map in another map let say some like: https://thecaveoflittlereik.000webhostapp.com/AppEvaRest/Storage/ITT_LaboratorioComputo.svg

It was that clear? I need the same point in both maps.

Comment: [gis.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) is a more appropriate place for this sort of question.

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](http://www.ijmse.org/Volume4/Issue6/paper2.pdf), published in 2013, reports some results about positional accuracies. It claims that, for horizontal coordinates, the root mean square   error is about $1.59$ meters.

[This other paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307936167_Evaluating_the_accuracy_of_Google_Earth_DEM_using_GPS_coordinates_Case_study_Duhok_Governorate), published in 2016, looks quite interesting.